# генерация RSS feed

Tags: python, django

**Задача**:

нужно создать генератор RSS-ленты.
к примеру: 
на вход поступает массив словарей - на выход xml-лента =)

**Что интересует**:

1. Какие библиотеки и инструменты для этого использовать?
2. Готовые примеры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Django есть средства для трансляции данных(RSS, Atom).
Для любой трансляции необходимо написать класс-представление `Feed` и указать его в urls . Трансляций может быть несколько.

Пример:
./views.py

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed

class TestFeed(Feed):
    title = "Test"
    link = "/testfeed/"
    description = "Test description."

    def items(self):
        return [{'title': 'test1', 'desc': 'Test Desc1'},
                {'title': 'test2', 'desc': 'Test Desc2'}]

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.desc
```

Подключаем url к трансляции.
 ./urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from testproject.views import TestFeed

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^feed/$', TestFeed()),
    # ...
]
```

Также, можно использовать свои шаблоны для генерации.
Более подробно можно прочесть в документации:
1. [Средства трансляции Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/syndication/),
2. [Средства трансляции Django (для старой версии на русском)](http://djbook.ru/ch11s05.html),